How to on being able to see on Viewport change The text
i am trying to on View change the text depending on which image being shown, like each img has its own description as i toggle on each image.
const [ObserveVis, setObserveVis] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver ((entries) => {
    const entry = entries[0];
    setObserveVis(entry.isIntersecting)
  })
  observer.observe(carouselRef.current)
},[])


i have this to log the ref container
<div ref={carouselRef} >
  {ProjectImg.map((img, index) => (
    <div key={index} >
      <img ref={imgRef1} onClick={() => window.open("https://snazzy-meerkat-f90f61.netlify.app/")} src={img} alt="My Project Image" />
       </div>
                    ))}
  </div>
                  
 <button onClick={scrollToPrevItem}>Prev</button>
 <button onClick={scrollToNextItem}  >Next</button>
     </div>
   </div>
      <p >{ObserveVis ? 'yes' : 'Nah'}</p>

If you explain what i be the next step id appreciate it

Here is my code

You will need an additional state to trach which image (and its corresponding description) is currently being viewed.



const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
const descriptions = [
  "Image Description1",
  "Image Description2",
  "Image Description3",
];




And update the index on image change



//Scroll to next item
setCurrentIndex(prevIndex => (prevIndex + 1) % ProjectImg.length);
//Scroll to previous item
setCurrentIndex(prevIndex => (prevIndex - 1 + ProjectImg.length) % ProjectImg.length);




Track current Visible Image



//Update useEffect 
useEffect(() => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        setCurrentIndex(Number(entry.target.getAttribute('data-index')));
      }
    });
  }, { threshold: 0.5 });

  document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item').forEach((item, index) => {
    item.setAttribute('data-index', index);
    observer.observe(item);
  });

  return () => observer.disconnect();
}, []);




Display the current image descirption



<p>{descriptions[currentIndex]}</p>




yea this was the correct way to do it, thanks alot i will study more of step 3 how u set it up.
